# How safe is windows' password system?

Tags: windows, command-line, passwords, windows-11

I have a question regarding the safety of the windows' password system. For a 2fa application, I'm interested to know if I can use the windows' hello pin feature to safeguard my tokens.

The reason I ask is that in earlier versions of windows, you could replace the sticky keys program with cmd.exe and get launched into an administrator command prompt on the login screen -> change a users password.

I'm curious if this still works and how it interacts with windows hello. If a theoretical person had theoretical access to my laptop, would they still be able to change the password and log into both my windows account and my 2fa app?

Comment: Why don't you try it and see?

Comment: note that to perform the accessibility options hack, you must have previously had access to the system as an admin to set up the backdoor. this is a type of evil butler/maid attack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should practice good and normal safety precautions:

1. In a public place, make sure your computer is locked if you are not using it.
2. Use Fingerprint access or like as that is very secure along with 2FA if you wish.
3. Keep a password program locked and closed unless using it. Secure such with a strong password.
4. Make sure remote access to your computer is not allowed or is protected by an extremely strong password,

You can easily secure your computer and you are very safe this way.

Review the link below and you can easily create passwords that will take more than a lifetime to crack.

[Password Protection](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-an-8-character-password-could-be-cracked-in-less-than-an-hour/https://)

> you could replace the sticky keys program with cmd.exe and get
> launched into an administrator command prompt on the login screen ->
> change a users password.

Make sure you strictly control access to your computer

Answer (score 0):

Nothing has changed in Windows as regarding that hack of entering the
Command Prompt without entering any password. It still works.

Whatever an attacker could do with your app is up to you to answer,
we can't know anything about it.

If you're worried about security, you could encrypt your disk using
Bitlocker, or stash your app inside a
[VeraCrypt](https://veracrypt.fr/en/Home.html) volume.